# Gatsby Build failing due to React context and window references

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering, react-context

I have a site built in Gatsby that is failing when I run `gatsby build`. The errors are happening because the SSR bundle is accessing dynamic content such as React context and the browser `document` and `window` objects.

For example, I have the following code in one of my pages that is trying to access `generalState`, a react context object. In this case, accessLevel is part of the context that manages user access on the site and the page should redirect home if the access level is not 1:

```
if (generalState.accessLevel > 1) {
  navigate('/');
}
```

But I get this error when trying build the SSR bundle:

```
WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'accessLevel')
```

I get similar errors when trying to access `window` or `document` in the components. I've read some answers that recommend wrapping all calls to the browser in a check. Something like:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  // do some stuff with window
}
```

I'd prefer not to do this, but I can if I need to. The context is the bigger issue though, because I rely heavily on react context in the app. Is it as simple as just using optional chaining in ***all*** of the references to context? That would be tedious, but possible. I feel that there is a better solution though.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tangential, but why are there "tons of calls to `window`"?

Comment: @DaveNewton I just went through the code and realized that was an exaggeration. ~10 calls is all. I wrapped them all but am now getting errors due to window calls in npm packages

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the errors that referenced `window` by wrapping all references in a check of some kind. Exactly as is shown here: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/#how-to-check-if-window-is-defined

The context issue was solved by creating a `gatsby-ssr.js` file and copying over all of code from `gatsby-browser.js`. This is where all of my context providers were defined and wrapping children. See here for an example: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-redux-w-interaction-code-splitting

After making those changes, the build worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using context to avoid passing props down nested components in Gatsby project, by providing default state to the Context will fix the Gatsby build issue

```
// example 
const defaultState = {
    count: 0,
    increment: () => {},
    decrement: () => {},
}

// Create a context
const Context = createContext(defaultState);
```